# Showing the fibre over a point in a covering map is a discrete space.

Tags: general-topology, covering-spaces

If $ p : \tilde Y \to Y$ is a covering map, how would you show that for every $y \in Y$ we have that $p^{-1}(y)$ is a discrete space?

Answer (score 4):

By definition $y$ has an open neighbourhood $U$ such that $p^{-1} [ U ]$ is a disjoint union of open subsets of $\tilde{Y}$, $\{ U_i : i \in I \}$, and $p \restriction U_i : U_i \to U$ is a homeomorphism for all $i$.  These $U_i$ then witness that $p^{-1} [ \{ y \} ]$ is a discrete subspace of $\tilde{Y}$.

Comment: How does $U_i$ witness that $p^{-1}[\{y\}]$ is a discrete subspace? I'm having trouble getting my head around 'defining' a discrete subspace as surely we want to say that each element of subset of $p^{-1}[\{y\}]$ is both open an closed?

Comment: ..under the definition of a discrete space? Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Note that a subspace $A \subseteq Z$ is discrete iff each $a \in A$ has an open neighbourhood $U$ in $Z$ such that $U \cap A = \{ a \}$.  The open sets $\{ U_i : i \in I \}$ will then witness this for the fiber of $f$ above $y$.